# Power Apps, Dropdown choice for column, Ascend/Descend based on Column choice

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I have a power app, I have listed my columns in the Item Section of a drop down:

[image]

[image]

How can I alter my Browse Gallery to Sort by Ascending/Descending based on my dropdown choice?

Current Browse Gallery Statement:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        "Title",
        If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        "Title",
        If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)
    )
)
```

The kind of pseudo code I'm trying to come up with:

`If Dropdown1.Value = "Documentation Type", Ascending, If Dropdown1.Value = "Requestor", Ascending", etc`

Trying to put it into the code is very confusing to me.

What I'm trying:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false Or Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value = "Approval Type",
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        "Title","DocType",
        If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)
        ),
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        "Title","DocType",
        If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)
    )
)
```

Comment: Currently you are using `SortDescending1` variable to sort the gallery. Do you want to continue using this variable along with dropdown selection to sort gallery or ignore this variable and just sort based on dropdown selection?

Comment: @GaneshSanap , Sorry should have clarified. I want to ignore the sort gallery and sory just based on dropdown selection.

Comment: Try using formula given in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula like below in `items` property of gallery control:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        "Title",
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type" || Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", Ascending, Descending)
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        "Title",
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type" || Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", Ascending, Descending)
    )
)
```

**Documentation**: [If and Switch functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-if)

---

**Update from comments**:

Use below formula to sort by column selected in dropdown:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value,
        Ascending
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value,
        Ascending
    )
)
```

**Note**: [Internal name of column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) based on which sorting is applied & dropdown option should be exact same. Also, there maybe some warnings related to delegation while using this formula.

---

If you have different column names & dropdown options, you can use formula like:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "DocType", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", "ID"),
        Ascending
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "DocType", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", "ID"),
        Ascending
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! if I want to add more to the dropdown is it as simple as adding items and using `|| ` to separated?   Also how will this sort if it is a Date based column?

Comment: Yes, you can add more conditions to same formula based on dropdown choices. Also, you might need to change the conditions if you want to sort based on date columns.

Comment: How does it work for requestor? My requestor fields are emails and should be ordered alphabetically?  But it isn't sorting like this when I drop down to requestor. Or is it doing it descending when I drop down? I think its only sorting based on "Title" column, is that correct? I need it to sort on each column

Comment: Just want to clarify: When you select "Requestor" in dropdown, do you want to sort gallery based on "Title" column or "Requestor" column? Also, when you select "Documentation Type" in dropdown, do you want to sort gallery based on "Title" column or any other column?

Comment: Sorry. When Requestor is selected, sort on Requestor. When Documentation Type is selected, Sort on Documentation Type and so on.

Comment: Check updated answer for updated formula.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Sigh one problem, is that my Choices in my dropdown are not the exact name of my columns lol. For example Items in my dropdown may say Requestor, but the name of the column in the list may be "Requestor_two" .  I believe your latest formula is looking for exact matches between dropdown and actual column names.

Comment: Check updated answer for updated formula in case you have different internal name of columns & dropdown options.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. What does "ID"  do?  Also do columns names have to be named without any spaces? Ie DocType cannot be Doc Type in the formula even if Doc Type is the column name in my MS List?  Im getting blanks when I add in additional choices to my drop down and modify your formula. However your Requestor drop down part is working fine!

Comment: "ID" will be used by default to sort gallery if previous conditions in formula do not satisfy. You have to use the internal names of columns.

Comment: thanks, and internal names of columns are those on the MS list?

Comment: Follow [this article](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html) to get internal name of columns. Also check documentation for sort functions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-sort